# autocomplete word from a list in tcsh

Tags: tcsh

Is there way in tcsh terminal to replace a word with a list of predefined phrases (possibly listed in a file)?

For example, I want to ssh to a server from a list of servers saved in a file. It would be convenient if I could type `ssh serv<TAB>` and `serv<TAB>` would be replaced with first entry of the server list file. Then I would use something like `<C-n>` to switch to the next entry of the file

Is this possible to do in tcsh?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `complete` command.

```
set hostlist=(server_abc server_xyz)
complete ssh      'p/1/$hostlist/'
```

More about the `complete` command.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=shell-complete-built-in-command-tcsh-list-completions